# Using Tablesorter to Sort tables which are generated from a dynamic SQL query

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

I'm currently working on a small project where I have an SQL Database that holds some data which I want to display in sortable tables.

I have already set up a Website which displays the tables. My problem is getting tablesorter working on these tables.

The website (http://tablesorter.com/) just gives an example for a single table.

Here's my sourcecode that's generated by PHP:

[Link](https://nopaste.xyz/?9399bced15c6baa4#kZBXrm5z2cfJVV5VA9udFCsvy6kQuGgWtDKN4F5vTPM=)

The code snippet which generates the tables is this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectedtanks)) {
$tank_id = $row[tank_id];
echo "<h2> ".tank_id2name($row[tank_id])." </h2><br>";
echo 
    "<table class=\"tablesorter\" id=\"myTable\">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Nickname</td>
                <td>Damage</td>
                <td>Frags</td>
                <td>Spots</td>
                <td>Wins</td>
                <td>Battles</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    ";
$sql = "select * from user2rooms left join usertanks on user2rooms.account_id=usertanks.account_id where user2rooms.room_id='$room_id' AND usertanks.tank_id='$tank_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>".account_id2name($row2[account_id])."</td>
        <td>".round($row2[damage_dealt]/$row2[battles],2)."</td>
        <td>".round($row2[frags]/$row2[battles],2)."</td>
        <td>".round($row2[spotted]/$row2[battles],2)."</td>
        <td>".round($row2[wins]/$row2[battles],4)*100 ."%</td>
        <td>".$row2[battles]."</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    ";
}
}
```

Code where JS get's added:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $(".tablesorter").css("border", "3px solid red");
} 
);
</script>
```

Comment: Every table you're generating has the same ID. You can't have elements with repeating ID's - they must be unique. Remove `id=\"myTable\"` from your table creation (or make it unique so that it appends a number based on loop iteration) and change your tablesorter initialization to be `$(".tablesorter").tablesorter();`.

Comment: I changed that and it sill doesn't work. It works for a hardcoded table, but not for the one generated by php

Comment: Edit your post to include the javascript where you initialize the tablesorter.

Comment: It's now included

Comment: Found the solution: I had to use <th> in <thead> instead of <td>

Comment: having worked with both, I prefer datatables.net over tablesorter.com